# Part 2 Another Question Regarding the Correct Wiring Involving a Light Switch and an Outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

Last week I started a thread that really confused me about some wiring in a bathroom. Here is that thread:

[My previous thread on rewiring a light in the bathroom.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131126/guidance-please-rewiring-the-light-switch-in-an-old-bathroom-house-that-i-cant)
Thanks to the help Jim Stewart, I was able to get the light in the ceiling to work. But now here is the thing. I finally figured out what the wiring in the lower right hand of the switch box is for. It is for an outlet on the opposite side of the wall that is in the hallway. I had no idea until I later learned that the hallway lamp wasn't working any longer. So my question is:

How do I connect the lower right hand Romex wiring in the junction box to the wiring that is described in the link above (per Jim Stewart's instructions) and connect it to the Romex that supplies power to the outlet in the hallway on the opposite side of the wall?

To recap in case you don't want to go to that other thread:

The upper left hand Romex in the switch box had a hot black wire. The other wire on the upper right hand was the wire that connected to the lamp I affixed into the ceiling. So to get it to turn the light on I connected the black hot wire of the Romex on the upper left to the black wire of the Romex on the upper right to a basic light switch. I then wired the white wire of the Romex on the upper left to the white wire of the Romex on the upper right. So now I need to figure out how to connect the Romex wire (that is located on the lower right hand side of the switch box that powers an electrical socket on the opposite wall to the upper left and/or right wiring in the same box. Here is the photo from the other thread:

Hope to get some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You connect the black wire of the cable going to the receptacle to the black (line hot) of the cable on the left. You connect the white wire of the cable going to the receptacle to the white neutral and connect the ground.

Before you do this you could examine the receptacle to determine that the receptacle is wired correctly or you could just connect it and test the receptacle with a circuit tester. The black wire should be go to the shorter slot and the white wire to the longer slot. If you have a multimeter, you can plug an extension cord into the receptacle and verify the hot neutral conections before you connect.